# Problems with NavController when unit testing an Ionic 2 app

Tags: unit-testing, ionic2, injectable

I'm having trouble unit testing with NavController.

I'm stuck at this error:

> Cannot resolve all parameters for 'NavController'(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'NavController' is decorated with Injectable.

I tried everything I found on the net, like using '@Inject', and nothing seems to work.

Here is the code:

**Component**

```
import {Page, MenuController, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {SignupPage} from '../signup/signup';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/welcome/welcome.html'
})
export class WelcomePage {

  //  Variables
  constructor(private menu: MenuController, private nav: NavController) {
    this.menu.enable(false);
  }

  goToSignupPage() {
    this.nav.push(SignupPage)
  }
}
```

**Unit test**

```
import {beforeEachProviders, it, describe, expect, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {MenuController, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {WelcomePage} from './welcome';

describe('WelcomePage', () => {

  beforeEachProviders(() => [WelcomePage, MenuController, NavController]);

  it('should have the menu disabled on instatiation', inject([WelcomePage], (welcomePage) => {

    // Expectations
    expect(welcomePage.menu.isEnabled()).toBeFalsy();

  }));

});
```

Any idea whats wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the replies, guys.

It really helped me to understand how to do it.

I didn't use `sinon`, but I was able to test if the `push` was called
using the `spyOn` from Jasmine.

For that, I did a subtle change to the `provide` part:

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [WelcomePage, MenuController,
{ provide: NavController, useValue: {push: NavController.prototype.push} }]);
```

(Probably it would be nice to serve the `NavController.prototype` directly to have access to all the other properties.)

And then tested like this:

```
it('should go to signup page when calling goToSignupPage()', 
inject([WelcomePage], (welcomePage) => {

  // Spies
  spyOn(welcomePage.nav, 'push').and.stub();

  // Call
  welcomePage.goToSignupPage();

  // Expectations
  expect(welcomePage.nav.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith(SignupPage);

}));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this on your Unit Test class:

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [WelcomePage, MenuController, provide(NavController, { useValue: WelcomePage })]);
```

and then:

```
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: Very helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As GoldBones, the problem is that the NavController that has been imported is a class not a provider, so you need to define your own provider. The `provide(...)` [syntax is deprecated](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/provide-function.html), but the final code is pretty similar to the old syntax:

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [WelcomePage, MenuController, {provide: NavController, useValue: {} }]);
```

I've used an empty object above, but as WelcomePage uses the `push` method, you will need to stub this out with something like:

```
let stubNavController = {push: (page) => {}};
beforeEachProviders(() => [WelcomePage, MenuController, {provide: NavController, useValue: stubNavController }]);
```

Using a spying library like [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) could be useful here if you want to test that the method was called.

Comment: Reference to dependency injection documentation. Covers valid usage of the "provide" and "useValue" along with other options. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#providers